# OpenLayer: Extent of KML lost and turned to [Infinity, Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity]?

Tags: gis, openlayers, qgis

I am trying to retrieve the extent of a KML layer I am bringing into OpenLayer.

When I open the KML layer in QGIS, I see there is extent information attached to it that I would like to use inside OpenLayer.

[image]

(Note: that extent information is "correct" => matches my expectations)

But when I load the layer in my script using `VectorSource` and `format: new KML()`, it seems as though the extent information is lost and turned into `[Infinity, Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity]`.

```
import VectorSource from "ol/source/Vector.js";
import KML from "ol/format/KML.js";

const model = new VectorSource({
      url: ".....",
      format: new KML(),
    });

console.log("model");
console.log(model);
console.log("model.getExtent()");
console.log(model.getExtent());
```

[image]

**My question:** Is there a way to *programmatically* retrieve the extent information I see in QGIS directly from within my OpenLayer script (by reading a property of the imported object rather than copy pasting manually from QGIS or some other data-source)?

Comment: [Infinity, Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity] means an empty extent.  The source must be loaded before you can access features and obtain their extent

Comment: Oh, thanks for the insight @Mike. Does it make sense to assume a promise timing issue then? How can I wait for the source to be properly loaded before running `getExtent()` on it?

Comment: Actually, I think `model` is not a promise (right?) so I am having a hard time figuring out how to wait for the source to load before querying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load the source you need to add it (in a layer) to a map

```
const model = new VectorSource({
      url: ".....",
      format: new KML(),
    });

model.once('featuresloadend', () => {
  console.log(model.getExtent());
});

map.addLayer(
  new VectorLayer({
    source: model,
  })
);
```

Alternatively fetch the url and read it with the KML format parser

```
const model = new VectorSource();

fetch( ".....")
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((text) => {
    model.addFeatures(
      new KML().readFeatures(text)
    );
    console.log(model.getExtent());
  });
```